# how to change hex coded javascript to redeable format

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have download mega menu , here was one jquery file, it was wrote in not understandable  language (may be in hex code) can you please  convert it into normal (understandable language)

code like this

```
var _0x1fb0 = ["\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67\x2C\x20\x2E\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x4C\x65\x66\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x6F\x70\x65\x6E", "\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x68\x61\x73\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x6D\x72\x67\x69\x6E\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72", "\x6F\x6E", "\x23\x6E\x61\x76\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x2C\x2E\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x70\x62\x6C\x61\x63\x6B\x62\x67", "\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77\x20\x66\x61\x20\x66\x61\x2D\x61\x6E\x67\x6C\x65\x2D\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E", "\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2C\x20\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x68\x61\x73", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x20\x6C\x69", "\x2E\x6D\x65\x67\x61\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x6C\x6F\x77", "\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x6D\x6F\x62\x69\x6C\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75", "\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x69\x6E\x67\x73", "\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x72\x6F\x74\x61\x74\x65", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x61\x72\x72\x6F\x77", "\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x73\x75\x62\x2D\x73\x75\x62", "\x2E\x77\x73\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"];
 $(function() {
     var _0x48ffx1 = $(_0x1fb0[0]);
     var _0x48ffx2 = $(_0x1fb0[1]);
     var _0x48ffx3 = function() {
         $(_0x48ffx1)[_0x1fb0[5]](_0x1fb0[4])[_0x1fb0[3]](_0x1fb0[2])
     };
     var _0x48ffx4 = function() {
         $(_0x48ffx1)[_0x1fb0[5]](_0x1fb0[2])[_0x1fb0[3]](_0x1fb0[4])
     };
     $(_0x1fb0[8])[_0x1fb0[7]](function() {
         if (_0x48ffx2[_0x1fb0[6]](_0x1fb0[2])) {
             $(_0x48ffx4)
         } else {
             $(_0x48ffx3)
         }
     });
     _0x48ffx2[_0x1fb0[7]](function() {
         if (_0x48ffx2[_0x1fb0[6]](_0x1fb0[2])) {
             $(_0x48ffx4)
         }
     });
     $(_0x1fb0[13])[_0x1fb0[12]](_0x1fb0[7], function() {
         $(_0x1fb0[11])[_0x1fb0[10]](_0x1fb0[9])
     });
     $(_0x1fb0[18])[_0x1fb0[17]](_0x1fb0[16])[_0x1fb0[15]](_0x1fb0[14]);
     $(_0x1fb0[18])[_0x1fb0[17]](_0x1fb0[19])[_0x1fb0[15]](_0x1fb0[14]);
     $(_0x1fb0[23])[_0x1fb0[7]](function() {
         $(_0x1fb0[22])[_0x1fb0[21]](_0x1fb0[20])
     });
     $(_0x1fb0[31])[_0x1fb0[7]](function() {
         $(this)[_0x1fb0[25]](_0x1fb0[24])[_0x1fb0[21]](_0x1fb0[20]);
         $(this)[_0x1fb0[28]](_0x1fb0[27])[_0x1fb0[10]](_0x1fb0[26]);
         $(this)[_0x1fb0[25]](_0x1fb0[29])[_0x1fb0[21]](_0x1fb0[20]);
         $(this)[_0x1fb0[25]](_0x1fb0[30])[_0x1fb0[21]](_0x1fb0[20]);
         $(this)[_0x1fb0[25]](_0x1fb0[19])[_0x1fb0[21]](_0x1fb0[20]);
     });
 });
```

Comment: use tool like http://jsnice.org/  to deobfuscator it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code, that you get from somewhere, called

> obfuscated

You need deobfuscator tool to do reverse process, to get original-like code.

Here some result from decoding with my tools:

```js
$(function() {
  var headings = $(".overlapblackbg, .slideLeft");
  var emptyJ = $(".wsmenucontent");
  /**
   * @return {undefined}
   */
  var backdrop = function() {
    $(headings).removeClass ("menuclose").addClass ("menuopen");
  };
  /**
   * @return {undefined}
   */
  var _element = function() {
    $(headings).removeClass ("menuopen").addClass ("menuclose");
  };
  $("#navToggle").click (function() {
    if (emptyJ.hasClass ("menuopen")) {
      $(_element);
    } else {
      $(backdrop);
    }
  });
  emptyJ.click (function() {
    if (emptyJ.hasClass ("menuopen")) {
      $(_element);
    }
  });
  $("#navToggle,.overlapblackbg").on ("click", function() {
    $(".wsmenucontainer").toggleClass ("mrginleft");
  });
  $(".wsmenu-list li").has (".wsmenu-submenu, .wsmenu-submenu-sub, .wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub").prepend ("<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>");
  $(".wsmenu-list li").has (".megamenu").prepend ("<span class="wsmenu-click"><i class="wsmenu-arrow fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>");
  $(".wsmenu-mobile").click (function() {
    $(".wsmenu-list").slideToggle ("slow");
  });
  $(".wsmenu-click").click (function() {
    $(this).siblings (".wsmenu-submenu").slideToggle ("slow");
    $(this).children (".wsmenu-arrow").toggleClass ("wsmenu-rotate");
    $(this).siblings (".wsmenu-submenu-sub").slideToggle ("slow");
    $(this).siblings (".wsmenu-submenu-sub-sub").slideToggle ("slow");
    $(this).siblings (".megamenu").slideToggle ("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: then you can mark the answer as correct :) Your welcome

Comment: can you please give me a link of website from where it was possibe to change?

Comment: can you please tell me which tool make it possible i have another js also